# Android Stages Progress

Tags: java, android, progress, rectangles

I would like to implement a progressbar with little circles/rectangles that shows the done stages from all stages like in the picture below.
For example you have to do 5 things and you already done 2, then the bar shows 2 green circles and 3 white ones or whatever.
Is there any native way to implement this?
Do you know a 3rd library that supports this?
Thank you for help!

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extended class of a view and implement the onDraw method and draw the circles, Google created a tutorial for it: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try to create it from scratch if noone else can show me a 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76). Pick whatever you like.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thats what I searched for. Thx a lot!